# Can you see movements of your own velum as you articulate?

Tags: phonetics, velar

This questions concerns the velum for phonetics. I am trying to control my velum and especially to billow it or curve it like a dome, per the 3 minutes and 45 seconds juncture of [this Youtube video](https://youtu.be/XXgnPbFhDxg?t=3m44s). [This other video](https://youtu.be/ahPHt_NCf-I) discusses more about the velum.

If you cannot see your own velum, then how else can I practice this?

PS: I first learned about the mobility of the velum from p 266, *Linguistics For Dummies* (1 ed, 2012; by Déchaine, Burton, Vatikiotis-Bateson)

Comment: A helpful picture: http://files.oscar-omar-sanchez-hernandez.webnode.es/200000017-a0976a18f9/24-910s07.jpg

Comment: A dental mirror is handy for this; or any adjustable mirror and adjustable light. The more important thing is to be able to feel it. For phonetics, I strongly recommend J.C. Catford's _Practical Introduction to Phonetics_, which is designed for self-study and contains many experiments and exercises.